# Restrict web page to only run in dev environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to restrict an MVC view to only be available in a development environment, and not be accessable from any other environments.

This is a test page that I don't want users to have access to if the site is running outside the developer environment. Either hosted locally under IIS or using the Visual Studio built-in Web Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can check if current Web Server is Visual Studio Development Server :</strike>

```
public static bool IsDevWebServer()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] == null || HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] == string.Empty;
}
```

Didn't noticed that you want that test page under local IIS, if you are allready using [web.config Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) (if not you should) and set some value under appSettings, for example :

```
<add key="DevEnv" value="True" />
```

and then transform it for release web config and set false  :

```
<add key="DevEnv" value="False" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking this would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Just set the redirect to that page to be 'http://localhost/path/file.aspx'

That should throw an error when they try and access the page. If you don't want to throw that error then you could redirect them to a different page when they try and access that outside of the test environment.